# Java GUI: How do I open an existing Form?

Tags: java, forms, swing, user-interface

I'm trying to reach an existing form that I made from another form. 
I want to click a button, and make the other form appear. Here's what I wrote:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class CustomerUI extends JFrame {

    public CustomerUI(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal)
    {        
        initComponents();        
        setTitle("Customer Data Input");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        Customer c = new Customer(jTextField1.getText(), jTextField2.getText(), jTextField3.getText());
        CinemaUI form = new CinemaUI();

        form.CUST.SetName(jTextField1.getText()); //Customer's Name
        form.CUST.SetID(jTextField2.getText()); //Customer's ID
        form.CUST.SetCard(jTextField3.getText()); //Customer's card
        form.NUM_OF_SEATS = Integer.parseInt(jTextField4.getText()); //Number of seats

        form.pack(); //Shows the next Form
        form.setVisible(true);
        CustomerUI.this.setVisible(false); //Hides this Form
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {


        /* Create and display the dialog */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                CustomerUI dialog = new CustomerUI(new javax.swing.JFrame(), true);
                dialog.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                });
                dialog.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }                  
}
```

CinemaUI is the name of the form I'd like to open.

After clicking jButton1 (the one I want to open the new window) I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
    at my.Cinema.CinemaUI.<init>(CinemaUI.java:30)
    at my.Cinema.CustomerUI.jButton1ActionPerformed(CustomerUI.java:126)
    at my.Cinema.CustomerUI.access$100(CustomerUI.java:11)
    at my.Cinema.CustomerUI$2.actionPerformed(CustomerUI.java:60)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

**Edit:**
I'll try explaining what my objective is:
A certain person wants to order tickets to a movie. I save his data (Name, credit card, etc.) using textboxes, and proceed to selecting the person's seats. The first window I'm looking at is the one with the textboxes, and after I click a button I want the Window that shows a list of available seats to show up (`CinemaUI`).

Thanks again for the help, I'm sorry its so long.

Comment: You should provide more info on what you are doing, but, don't have one form open another form and hide itseft, you should have some kind of controller, opening and closing the forms.

Comment: I edited the post a little, hope its enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for somthing like this:

```
public class Form extends JFrame {

    public Form(){
        JButton show = new JButton("show Form2");
        show.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                new Form2();
                Form.this.setVisible(false);
            }

        });
        setTitle("Form 1");
        getContentPane().add(show,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    class Form2 extends JFrame {

        public Form2(){
            JButton show = new JButton("show Form");
            show.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    new Form();
                    Form2.this.setVisible(false);
                }

            });
            setTitle("Form 2");
            getContentPane().add(show,BorderLayout.CENTER);
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            pack();
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            setVisible(true);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Form();
    }
}
```

I hope it helps you.

According you `Form` is form for credentials and `Form2` is `CinemaUI`.

Comment: I tried using what you wrote, but I'm still getting the same error as before. I added the Output, hope you know what it means. Thanks again!

Comment: what is in 30 line in `CinemaUI`?

Comment: where is your `initComponents();` in `CinemaUI` I think problem in it.

Answer (score 2):

I found my problem. I shouldv'e made a new JFrame instead of a new 'class'. That way it worked fine using this example:

```
Form1 form = new Form1();
form.setVisibile(true);
this.setVisibile(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Errr... without any details on CinemaUI implementation, it's going to be a bit hard to help. Let's assume CinemaUI extends JFrame. Are you sure you called pack() on it first ? If it's not a frame, you're probably already in a frame of some sort... so you should add CinemaUI to it first.